# get folder structure for a magento extension

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, xml

I have added many extensions in my mangento.  Now i want to retrieve the folder structure of each extensions, if file exists in app/design/frontend folder also.  How to get the file structure?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a way rather than an understanding as to [how modules are structured](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config). Here are a few tips from personal experience:

1. Look in **/app/etc/modules/** note there are 2 sections for each file name. The first is the name of the module manufacturer, the second is the name of the module. For this example **AW_Blog.xml**
2. If you look at the XML file, there will be a section "**codePool**"  this will tell you if it is a **community** module, **local** module or a **code** module.
3. All code for modules are stored in **/app/code** - since our module indicated **community** we will look in the **community** subdirectory.
4. The structure will now be directory with the name of the module manufacturer followed by a sub-directory which will be the name of the module. All code relating to the module will be within these directories.
5. If the module does any styling or has more functionality than straight code, it will have a XML layout file located in **/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout** with the same naming convention as #1. Our example again **aw_blog.xml**
6. Looking in **/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/** you will find again the same naming convention, however in a directory structure. First section the manufacturer name seperated by a _ then the module name. Example directory **aw_blog**. with all related code within that directory.

Notes: For local modules and layout files you will need to look in **/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout** and **/app/design/frontend/base/default/template** respectively.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the structure.  The above steps we have to check manually.  I need the path of all files programmatically

Comment: No problem, I've edited your question to reflect what you were looking for. Not sure if its possible though. SR